# How to remove content from view once user clicks on it (or reads it) in drupal 7?

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, users, flags, nodes

I have a view "Recent content of your interest" based on taxonomy and flag.

Current scenario:

User clicks on content from view and reads it, he comes back to same view.

What I want:

User clicks on content from view, read it, come back and the content (which he just read) is not listed i.e. removed from same view.

Any module I can use for same or any pointer to implement same functionality highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement by altering query of view.

**history** table of your database stores the record whether any content is accessed in past or not.

You can check whether logged in user has visited this node in past or not.

function [node_last_viewed](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_last_viewed/7)($nid) returns the timestamp when node is viewed last. If node is not accessed then it will return 0.

So you can customize the query and put the condition to check whether node is accessed in last or not and you have to display only nodes which are not accessed in past.

[See here](http://mohitaghera.drupalgardens.com/content/how-check-whether-any-node-accessed-past-or-not) for one more use case. Though it is not using views but it will guide you to solutions.

Comment: Note - using views query alter hook should always be the last resort as it makes the view/code a lot harder to maintain, than configuring your view to behave like you want.

Answer (score 5):

You can use rules and flag module.

Create a view that list related content that the user hasn't flagged.

Create a rule that flags the content when is viewed by the user.

Setup the flag so the it doesn't show up on the node view.

Comment: that's easy way but choosing @mohit_rocks answer as final because i have to do lot more manipulation with content in my custom modules.

Comment: @prady, getting flag values via code is pretty easy.